# Refactor jquery (coffescript) code with checkboxes

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, jquery-ui

I have two different set of checkboxes. With the coffescript code below I set the maximum amount of checkable items at 3. I would like to refactor this code, to be cleaner and compact, but I can't get it.

```
$("div.feature_list :checkbox").click ->
  if $("div.feature_list :checked").length >= 3
    $("div.feature_list :checkbox:not(:checked)").attr "disabled", "disabled"
    $("div.feature_list :checkbox:not(:checked)").button disabled: true
  else
    $("div.feature_list :checkbox:not(:checked)").button disabled: false

$("div.style_list :checkbox").click ->
   if $("div.style_list :checked").length >= 3
     $("div.style_list :checkbox:not(:checked)").attr "disabled", "disabled"
     $("div.style_list :checkbox:not(:checked)").button disabled: true
   else
     $("div.style_list :checkbox:not(:checked)").button disabled: false
```

Comment: FYI, to enable/disable a button use `.prop('disabled', true_or_false)` instead of setting the attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: DRY. Encapsulate the "limit checkboxes" behavior in a function

```
limitCheckboxesIn = (container, limit = 3) ->
  checkboxes = $(container).find ":checkbox"
  checkboxes.on "click", (event) ->
    checked   = checkboxes.filter ":checked"
    unchecked = checkboxes.not checked
    state     = disabled: checked.length >= limit
    unchecked.prop(state).button state
```

Step 2: ... well, that pretty much it. Call it like so:

```
$ ->
  limitCheckboxesIn "div.feature_list"
  limitCheckboxesIn "div.style_list"
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7C3Z7/3/)

By the way, if you just want the most compact solution, you can skip some assignments:

```
limitCheckboxesIn = (container, limit = 3) ->
  checkboxes = $(container).find ":checkbox"
  checkboxes.on "click", (event) ->
    disabled = checkboxes.filter(":checked").length >= limit
    checkboxes.not(":checked").prop({disabled}).button {disabled}
```

Personally, I find this a little less readable, but it's a matter of taste; the code's functionally identical.

Comment: It works with plain checkboxes but it doesnt work with jquery ui buttonset. I think the last line should be different

Comment: @framomo86 Whoops, you're right - I've corrected my answer, and the demo.